# PhpStorm Ubuntu 18.041 browsers do not start

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm in Ubuntu 18.041 and facing a serious problem.

I've tried several configurations (JavaScript, PHP remote) with Chrome and Firefox but none of them is starting the browser. I do not get any error message, the browser window just do not appear.

Comment: Contact PhpStorm support directly via Help > Contact Support

Comment: what do your web browsers settings (**Settings | Tools | Web Browsers**) look like? Can you open browsers from the browsers bar in editor or using **View | Open in browser** main menu? Also, what about **Help | Help** main menu? I'd suggest contacting support, providing the detailed problem description and idea.log

Comment: The path for e.g. firefox is "firefox". When I execute firefox in a terminal window the browser starts normally. And it also does not start in the browser bar

Comment: I just noticed that also "Help->Contact Support" is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service desk helped me to solve this issue. It seems that the installation was not completed correctly. I started PHPStorm from the shell and it lead me again trough the initial configuration. Since that is is working normally.